# I need help understanding "the inverse"

Tags: cryptography

Towards the bottom of this [page](http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/affine-cipher/). where it says `Solving systems of equations modulo 26 is slightly more difficult than solving them normally, but it is still quite easy`

How did D go from -15 to 11?

and how is the inverse of D 19? I don't understand how these numbers came up

Comment: -15 = 11 mod 26.

Comment: What is $D$ in the question?

Answer (score 1):

-15 = 11 mod 26.
11*19 mod 26 = 1.

Comment: $11$ and $-15$ are the same element in the ring $\mathbb Z / 26\mathbb Z$. More precisely, the sets $\{11 + 26n \ | \ n \in \mathbb Z\}$ and $\{-15 + 26n \ | \ n \in \mathbb Z\}$ are equal. Also, $\{11 * 19 + 26n \ | \ n \in \mathbb Z\} = \{1 + 26n \ | \ n \in \mathbb Z\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 26\!:\, {-}15 \equiv 26-15 \equiv 11,\:$ and $\rm\ \dfrac{1}{-15}\equiv\dfrac{-1}{15}\equiv \dfrac{25}{15}\equiv\dfrac{5}{3}\equiv\dfrac{-21}{3}\equiv -7\equiv 19$

While tricks like the above often work to compute inverses for small moduli, for larger moduli  it is more efficient to use the [extended Euclidean algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

Answer (score 1):

Typically when working with $\mod n$ arithmatic, and especially in applications to arithmetic, we want a numerical value between 0 and $n-1$. When a result is outside of this range, we can add or subtract $n$ enough times to get it into the correct range. In this particular situation, -15 becomes 11 by adding 26 to it.

As to your second question, we can check that 19 is the inverse of 11 $\mod n$ by multiplying them: $11 \cdot 19 = 209$. Now we subtract 26 from 209 until we get a number between 0 and 26. Equivalently, we can divide 209 by 26 and take the remainder, which is 1 in this case. Therefore, $11 \cdot 19 \equiv 1 \mod 26$.

Now if you want to find the inverse of a number, rather than just check for an inverse, we need to use the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). (I won't describe it here. If you are unfamiliar with it, you should visit the link.) For this problem, we proceed as follows:

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
26 &=& 2 \cdot 11 &+& 4 \\
11 &=& 2 \cdot 4 &+& 3  \\
4 &=& 1 \cdot 3 &+& 1
 \end{eqnarray}$$

Now that we have reached a remainder of $1$, we rewrite each equation as follows:

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
4 &=& 26 &-& 2 \cdot 11 \\
3 &=& 11 &-& 2 \cdot 4  \\
1 &=& 4 &-& 1 \cdot 3
 \end{eqnarray}$$

Now we work backwards, substituting and simplifying along the way:

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
1 &=& 4 - 1 \cdot 3 = 4 - 1 \cdot \left( 11 - 2 \cdot 4 \right) \\
  &=& -1 \cdot 11 + 3 \cdot 4 = -1 \cdot 11 + 3 \cdot \left( 26 - 2 \cdot 11  \right) \\
  &=& -7 \cdot 11 + 3 \cdot 26
\end{eqnarray}$$

Now we see that $-7 \cdot 11 \equiv 1 \mod 26$. This means that $-7$ is the inverse of $11\mod 26$. Since we have a negative number, we add $26$ to get $19$!

If you have difficulty following this, I strongly suggest that you review modular arithmetic and the Euclidean algorithm.