# Using Euler's totient theorem to compute $11^{-1}$ mod $26$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse, totient-function

I tried to solve this modular inverse equation: $11^{-1}$ mod $26$ with Fermat's little theorem: $a^{\phi (m) - 1} * a \equiv 1$ mod $m$ and reached the following solution:

$11^{\phi (26)-1} * 11 \equiv 1$ mod $26$

$\phi (26) = 12$

$11^{11} * 11 \equiv 1$ mod $26$

Resulting in: $11^{12} \equiv 1$ mod $26$ with the modular inverse of $11$ being $11^{11}$.

Now I'm wondering if my calculations are correct or if there is a different approach and if this generally works this way.

Comment: Presumably one wants the least positive representative of the inverse, so you should reduce $11^{11}\pmod {26}$.  Note that it is somewhat simpler to work $\pmod {13}$ and use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Smaller moduli tend ot be easier to work with numerically.

Comment: Also worth noting:  with numbers as small as this, just searching for the inverse is very fast and reliable.

Comment: $26=2\cdot 13$, so you can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042302/proving-identities-mod-pq-using-fermats-little-theorem?rq=1). See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185579/i-need-help-understanding-the-inverse#:~:text=Now%20we%20see%20that%20%E2%88%927,inverse%20of%2011mod26.). So $19$ is the inverse.

Comment: That’s Euler’s theorem. Not that it matters much.

Answer (score 0):

When the numbers are fairly small one can take advantage of a some basic arithmetic.

Since $\;11\cdot7=77=-1\pmod{26}\;$, because $\;26\cdot3=78\;$ , we get:

$$11\cdot(-7)=1\pmod {26}\,,\,\text{and since}\;-7=19\pmod{26}\,,\,\text{we get}\;11^{-1}=19\pmod{26}$$